# Почему изменение UI необходимо запускать в Main Queue в iOS и macOS

Tags: ios, macos, очередь, планировщик-задач, main

Привет всем. Я пишу приложения на iOS и mac, но только недавно возник банальный вопрос, который я воспринимал как аксиому: "Почему нужно запускать обновление интерфейса на main queue?".

Как я понимаю, это связано с тем, как планировщик заданий работает с процессами: планировщик для дочернего (параллельного) процесса делает доступной область памяти основного процесса, но при попытке изменения каких-либо данных происходит копирование этой области памяти и флаг с чтения меняется на чтение и запись. В iOS и mac это изменение отлавливает ядро и чаще всего корректно изменяет значение исходной области памяти, в противном случае не изменяется либо крашится приложение. Так происходит в Linux, на сколько я помню. А как в iOS и macOS? Поправьте если я где-то ошибаюсь, пожалуйста.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Первая причина: все лейблы, текстовые поля и тд являются потомками UIApplication, который запускается на главном потоке.

Вторая причина: обработка графической информации на айфоне является синхронной операцией. Изображение обновляется до 60 раз в секунду, а графическая информация должна обновляться единовременно. К примеру, если изменяется текст на лейбле с асинхронного потока, то можно получить множество недостающих деталей, потому что обработка для этой части не была готова, когда весь экран был визуализирован.

Третья причина: так проще.

Comment: Всё-таки UILabel, UITextField и т.п. потомками UIApplication не являются. UIApplication – это вообще синглтон. Они являются потомками UIResponder, события с подклассов которого обрабатываются в главном runloop'е, который и связан с главным потоком.

Comment: Но это объяснение, мне кажется, лучше, чем ниже:)

Answer (score 2):

Изменять UI с главного потока (а именно на главном потоке выполняется Main Queue) - это распространенная практика, встречающаяся в подавляющем большинстве фреймворков для пользовательского интерфейса. Так происходит в Cocoa, Cocoa Touch, WinAPI, UWP, Android, QT, Swing, JavaFX и так далее.

Эти фреймворки работают на огромном разнообразии платформ, как программных, так и аппаратных, и ответ на вопрос, почему так сделано, просто не может быть привязан к архитектуре конкретной платформы.

В книге 'Windows via C/C++' автор предполагает, что изменение UI из единственного потока повсеместно принято по причине своей **простоты** - мы всегда знаем, что UI изменяется в одном месте и никогда не сталкиваемся с типичными проблемами параллелизма, если у нас всего один поток. Просто представьте, что все потоки меняют UI и синхронизовать их должны вы как программист - к чему такое усложнение?

Comment: То есть абсолютно без разницы на какой очереди изменять UI, верно понял? А изменение на main queue принято как стандарт. Ведь если так, то, выходит, вывод в консоли Xcode лжёт, что приложение может крашиться и некорректно работать? Если не говорить об адской архитектуре приложения, где куча потоков меняет UI.

Comment: В данном случае, конкретно Cocoa разработан с предположением, что UI меняется только с главного потока. Вывод Xcode не лжёт - мы действительно получим неопределенное поведение иначе. А изменение UI с разных потоков - не обязательно адская архитектура, библиотека Texture от Facebook разрешает так делать для достижения асинхронного рендеринга и плавности интерфейса (однако изнутри она все равно зовёт UIKit на главной очереди).

Comment: Т.е. неопределённое поведение будет связано с тем, что можно предположить, что будут некорректно синхронизироваться данные в UI и параллельном потоке из-за невозможности предположить, какое действие выполнится раньше? Т.е. фактически нет никакой разницы, если смотреть со стороны ОС (планировщика заданий), а необходимость изменять интерфейс с главного потока обусловлена, грубо говоря, тем, что так проще отследить последовательность действий на UI? Собственно этот момент и не могу понять. В чём именно фундаментальная разница, кроме того что так принято.

Comment: Это вопрос не к ОС, а к конкретному фреймворку. Представьте, что вы пишете библиотеку. При её проектировании необходимо однозначно дать понять, как её использовать во многопоточной среде (например, при выборе libc в WinAPI выбор однопоточной версии приводит к падениям во многопоточной программе). Если проектировать UI библиотеку, гораздо удобнее и эффективнее предполагать, что её функции вызываются на главном потоке - иначе разработчикам библиотеки нужно все синхронизировать, что повлечет огромный overhead в рантайме, когда как эта синхронизация будет не нужна в 99% случаев.